# SQL Query to Find Min and Max Values between Values, dates and companies in the same Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is to find the historic max and min price of a stock in the same query for every past 10 days from the current date. below is the data. I've tried the query but getting the same high and low for all the rows. The high and low needs to be calculated per stock for a period of 10 days.

RDBMS -- SQL Server 2014

Note: also duration might be past 30 to 2months if required ie... 30 days. or 60 days.
for example, the output needs to be like ABB,16-12-2019,1480 (MaxClose),1222 (MinClose) (test data) in last 10 days.

```
+------+------------+-------------+
| Name |    Date    |    Close    |
+------+------------+-------------+
| ABB  | 26-12-2019 | 1272.15     |
| ABB  | 24-12-2019 | 1260.15     |
| ABB  | 23-12-2019 | 1261.3      |
| ABB  | 20-12-2019 | 1262        |
| ABB  | 19-12-2019 | 1476        |
| ABB  | 18-12-2019 | 1451.45     |
| ABB  | 17-12-2019 | 1474.4      |
| ABB  | 16-12-2019 | 1480.4      |
| ABB  | 13-12-2019 | 1487.25     |
| ABB  | 12-12-2019 | 1484.5      |
| INFY | 26-12-2019 | 73041.66667 |
| INFY | 24-12-2019 | 73038.33333 |
| INFY | 23-12-2019 | 73036.66667 |
| INFY | 20-12-2019 | 73031.66667 |
| INFY | 19-12-2019 | 73030       |
| INFY | 18-12-2019 | 73028.33333 |
| INFY | 17-12-2019 | 73026.66667 |
| INFY | 16-12-2019 | 73025       |
| INFY | 13-12-2019 | 73020       |
| INFY | 12-12-2019 | 73018.33333 |
+------+------------+-------------+
```

The query I tried but no luck

```
select  max([close]) over (PARTITION BY name) AS MaxClose,
        min([close]) over (PARTITION BY name) AS MinClose,
        [Date],
        name
from    historic
where   [DATE] between   [DATE] -30 and [DATE]
        and name='ABB'
group by [Date],
        [NAME],
        [close]
order by [DATE] desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a running min/max

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,MinClose = min([Close]) over (partition by name order by date rows between 10 preceding and current row)
      ,MaxClose = max([Close]) over (partition by name order by date rows between 10 preceding and current row)
From YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the highest and lowest `close` per `name`, then simple aggregation is enough:

```
select name, max(close) max_close, min(close) min_close
from historic
where close >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate())
group by name
order by name
```

If you want the entire corresponding records, then `rank()` is a solution:

```
select name, date, close
from (
    select
        h.*,
        rank() over(partition by name order by close) rn1,
        rank() over(partition by name order by close desc) rn2
    from historic h
    where close >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate())
) t
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1
order by name, date
```

Top and bottom ties will show up if any.

You can add a `where` condition to filter on a given `name`.

Comment: Thanks GMB, I got your approach but need running min/max for every 10 days.